# 'I was not interested in this job { before/earlier }' - which is correct?

Tags: word-choice

> 1. I was not interested in this job before
> 2. I was not interested in this job earlier

Which one is correct and how to use them i.e. "before" and "earlier"

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences refer to an implied earlier time at which you were not interested in this job. Since this implied time/event, example 1 indicates that you have become interested in this job.

Thus it's correct to say: "I was not interested in this job before (the implied time or event but I am interested now).

Example 2 has a double negative (whether by design or in error). It says that you were NOT NOT interested....  That's to say that you were interested.

Whatever the case, either "earlier" or "before" mean exactly the same thing in this context - that it was after the implied time/event that your attitude to the job changed. Both words are acceptable.